# MUI: cannot override fontFamily through theme nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to have different parts of my application have different fonts. I want to achieve this through theme nesting: https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#theme-nesting.

But theme nesting doesn't work when overriding fonts.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import outerTheme from "./outerTheme";
import innerTheme from "./innerTheme";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={outerTheme}>
      <Button>outer</Button>
      <Typography color="primary">outer</Typography>
      <ThemeProvider theme={innerTheme}>
        <Button>inner</Button>
        <Typography color="primary">inner</Typography>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

outerTheme.js:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const outerTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ff0000",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  },
});

export default outerTheme;
```

innerTheme.js:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";
import outerTheme from "./outerTheme";

const innerTheme = createTheme(outerTheme, {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#0000ff",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "serif",
  },
});

export default innerTheme;
```

The result shows that all buttons and typographies use the outer theme's font (i.e. sans-serif) but use the correct respective theme colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested theme works, it's just that your `fontFamily` is never set in the first place. If you want to override the `Button`'s font family, you need to set the value in `typography.button.fontFamily`, not `typography.fontFamily` ([Source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L77)):

```
const outerTheme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    button: {
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    },
  },
});

const innerTheme = createTheme(outerTheme, {
  typography: {
    button: {
      fontFamily: 'serif',
    },
  },
});
```

**EDIT:** To override the `fontFamily` of all MUI components, you need to update all variants:

```
function createFontFamily(fontFamily) {
  return {
    h1: { fontFamily },
    h2: { fontFamily },
    h3: { fontFamily },
    h4: { fontFamily },
    h5: { fontFamily },
    h6: { fontFamily },
    subtitle1: { fontFamily },
    subtitle2: { fontFamily },
    body1: { fontFamily },
    body2: { fontFamily },
    button: { fontFamily },
    caption: { fontFamily },
    overline: { fontFamily },
  };
}
```

```
const outerTheme = createTheme({
  typography: createFontFamily('sans-serif'),
});
const innerTheme = createTheme(outerTheme, {
  typography: createFontFamily('serif'),
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This is just a simplified example. In my actual scenario the inner theme wraps around a large component tree. I want to override the font across many components.

Comment: @Kazuto_Ute you can, see my codesandbox for reference, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I mean I will use many different types of components: Button, Typography, TextField, etc. I only use Button here as an example. Ideally I would like to specify the font override once. Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier.

Comment: @Kazuto_Ute see my updated answer.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use the allVariants rather than set all items individually. eg:
`typography: {
  allVariants: {
      fontFamily: 'serif',
    },
},`